# Lower bound on $\frac{f(σ(n))}{f(n)}$ where $n = \prod\limits_i p_i^{e_i}, f(n) = \prod\limits_i \frac{p_i+1}{p_i}$ and $σ$ is the divisor function.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

If $n$ has the prime factorization $\prod\limits_i p_i^{e_i}$ for distinct primes $p_i$ and exponents $e_i > 0,$ the sum of divisors is $\sigma(n) = \prod\limits_i \frac{p_i^{e_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}.$ I'm solving a problem involving sequences of abundant numbers and need an estimate on $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ to continue. We have the plain estimate $$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \prod\limits_i \frac{p_i - p_i^{-e_i}}{p_i - 1} \ge \prod\limits_i \frac{p_i - p_i^{-1}}{p_i - 1} = \prod\limits_i \frac{p_i + 1}{p_i} := f(n),$$ and now I need an estimate on $f(n).$

Specifically, I want to make sure that $f$ does not crash too much when the divisor function is applied, and so would like a lower bound on $\frac{f(\sigma(n))}{f(n)}.$ Is there any non-trivial lower bound?

Comment: The notation $d(n)$ usually means $\sigma_0(n)$ (or otherwise known as $\tau(n)$ in some textbooks), whereas you mean $\sigma_1(n)=\sigma(n)$ here, @Displayname.

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris Fixed.